# Plotting data imported from Excel and overlaying it on a disk

Tags: plotting, data, csv-format

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to get the hang of plotting data from an external CSV file. The data is just `x, y, z` values from an experiment I ran. I would like to plot the `x, y, z` values and then overlay them onto a disk in 3D. It should look like the green image below that I got that from a former colleague and I believe, the spike in the circle comes from taking one `x, y, z` point from the Excel file and overlaying it on a circle or disk. I currently have code that generates a disk. Any help is much appreciated.

```
disk3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] := 
 Polygon[Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre]][
     If[First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi, #, Append[#, centre]] &[
      Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &][
       SortBy[#, sortf[#, Most@centre] &] &[
        MeshCoordinates[
         DiscretizeRegion[
          Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]]]]]]]]

sortf := Composition[If[Negative[#], # + 2 Pi, #] &, N[ArcTan @@ (#1 - #2)] &]

disk = disk3D[{400, 400, 400}, 400];
disk1 = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Green, disk}]
```

Data from the csv file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `Show[disk1, ListPointPlot3D[yourdata]]`?

Comment: Are you saying that each spike on the graph is caused by a single data point, or is the full dataset much larger? Is the data collected on a grid, and most of the values are zero? Unless you generate a `Sinc` function or something for each data point, I'm not entirely sure how you get the plot above from the dataset posted.

Comment: .. or try  `Show[disk1, ListPlot3D[yourdata]]`?